# Enable data compression in API Gateway using the Serverless framework or CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

Following the Serverless framework documentation, I added this to my `serverless.yaml`

```
provider:
  name: aws
  apiGateway:
    minimumCompressionSize: 1
```

So, I have any given endpoint for testing, it returns a JSON string of approximately 500 characters, which, according to my configuration above, should return compressed, but as we can verify through cURL, it does not come compressed.

```
functions:
  v1-http-dummy:
    handler: app/v1/http/dummy.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /v1/dummy
          method: GET
```

Checking:

```
$ curl -X POST -sILH 'Accept-Encoding: *' https://example.com/v1/dummy
HTTP/2 404 
date: Thu, 16 Nov 2023 10:19:13 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 23
apigw-requestid: OfHpQg_xIAMEJwA=
```

Without any signs of compression.

I'm aware there is a difference between REST API and HTTP API; my project utilizes HTTP API. My question is, how can I enable compression on API Gateway using Serverless framework?

It could also be through CloudFormation.

I tried an answer I found on StackOverflow, but it doesn't work anymore, which is why I am asking again. Hence, this should not be considered a duplicate question because the old solution is no longer effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify that you want to receive compressed response: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-receive-response-with-compressed-payload.html

Also a note, if you want to enable compression for all requests/responses, you can set the value to `0`. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_RestApi.html#minimumCompressionSize

EDIT: After our conversation, I've realised that you're using `httpApi` event type, while `apiGateway` settings on provided only apply to `http` event type and compression setting is only available for `http` event type. If your case, you could use the `http` event instead of `httpApi` like below:

```
functions:
  v1-http-dummy:
    handler: app/v1/http/dummy.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: v1/dummy
          method: GET
```

For differences between `httpApi` and `http` events please see the docs:

- `http` event docs: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway
- `httpApi` event docs: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api

Comment: I did, 'Accept-Encoding: *'. Other sites works.

Comment: Did you try specifying e.g. `Accept-Encoding: gzip`?

Comment: Of course I tried

Comment: As I said, other sites works, it not a problem on my command, it is a problem on AWS side (my config)

Comment: Ah, after re-reading your config again and thinking of potential options I realized what might be causing it. You're setting the compression on `apiGateway`, however, the `apiGateway` config only applies to APIGW v1 (REST) (`http` event type in serverless), while your function is using `httpApi`, which uses APIGW v2 (HTTP). Please switch to `http` even type, deploy and try again. As the syntax for that event is a bit different, you might want to consult the docs: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway

Comment: Can you give ma example, not sure if I understood correctly.

Comment: Hey @Rodrigo, I've edited my answer above to be able to provide better formatting than in the comment. Please let me know if that works for you and/or if you have any further questions